# How to get the index of the current NavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

So in here i want to change some condition if my tabview switch to the second tab but i don't know how to get the tabbar index, already try this and that. Im hoping some solution without statefull, Im using GetX thanks.

im planning to change the `extendBody: true,` in my main page to false when the tab switch to the second tab i had the logic for that hopefully but the only problem is the index :(.

My tabs :

```dart
   List<Tab> myTabs = [
      Tab(
        text: 'Following',
      ),
      Tab(
        text: 'Trending',
      ),
      Tab(
        text: 'Search',
      ),
    ];
```

DefaultController code :

```
DefaultTabController(
      length: myTabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        // APPBAR
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          toolbarHeight: 60,
          // BOTTOM
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                labelStyle: poppins.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: bold,
                ),
                unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff585861),
                indicatorColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                // TABS
                tabs: myTabs,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            FollowingTab(),
            TrendingTab(),
            search(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Hey i think you need to define your currentIndex into controller file and use here. Can you clarify that  you need to change bottomBar index or TabBar index both are different.

Comment: Its different, in first index of bottombar is homepage that have 3 tab

Comment: Please don't use image or screenshot instead copy and paste the overall program also visit https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: okay thanks to inform me i completely didn't know about that

Comment: check out i suggest my answer.

Comment: Please learn stateful widget first, go to https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive. Don't overcomplicated your problem by using Getx as a crutch.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TabBar` with `TabController` and you can find current index while switching to next tab

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 6, vsync: this);
    _controller!.addListener(() {
      print(_controller!.index);
    });
  }
```

your build method be like:

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
       bottom:TabBar(
        controller: _controller,
        tabs:[
         //your tabs will be here
        ]
       ),
       body:TabBarView(
       controller: _controller,
       children: [
         //your tabbarview will be here
        ]
       ),
     );
   }
```

Comment: for the initState does it have to use statefull widget ? im new with state management and i only understand GetX a bit

Comment: you got to initilize tabbarcontroller that is why initState is needed, or you can use stateless widget but you have to create getx controller and then you can initilize your stuff in onInit() which you can override in getx contrroler

Answer (score 0):

Here i just code of **Tabbar** with using **Getx** and **Stateless** Widget.

CheckOut my code and if you find solution then give up me. Thanks in advance

```
class TabDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  TabDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final DemoController demoController = Get.put(DemoController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.flight)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            ],
          ),
          title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: demoController.controller?.value,
          children: const [
            Icon(Icons.flight, size: 350),
            Icon(Icons.directions_transit, size: 350),
            Icon(Icons.directions_car, size: 350),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You need to create **controller** class to define controller and initmethod

```
class DemoController extends GetxController with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
  Rx<TabController>? controller;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    controller?.value = TabController(length: 6, vsync: this);
    controller?.value.addListener(() {
      print(controller?.value.index);
    });
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```